# Sequence of random variables and limits

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be a sequence of random variables. I want to show that there exists a sequence $\{A_n\}$ , where $A_n > 0$ for all $n$, such that:
$$ P(\{ \omega \in \Omega: \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X_n(\omega)}{A_n}=0\}) =1.$$

For this I've been told that I should use $P(\{ |X_n|>\frac{A_n}{n} \})\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$. My first question is: how to prove this? I have an intuition of why it is true, but don't know how to write it down.

Then, I know that because of the Borel Cantelli lemma I can write
$$
P(\{ \frac{|X_n|}{A_n} > \frac{1}{n}\ \quad \text{i.o.}\})=0
$$
which leads that there is some measurable set in which $P(\{ \frac{|X_n|}{A_n} \leq \frac{1}{n}\ \})=1$. My second question is how to guarantee that this happens for some $n > N$ to take the limit and conclude the proof.

Comment: For the first question, can you show, for each $n$, that $\lim_{x\to\infty}P(X_n > x) = 0$?  For the second one, I think you've misinterpreted the complement of $$\left\{\frac{|X_n|}{A_n} > \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{i.o.}\right\}$$  If you interpret it correctly, the limit is precisely what pops out. (Note that "$N$" will depend on $\omega$, but this is what you want)

Comment: @BrianMoehring: For the first question, well, I actually proved that $\lim_{x \to \infty} P(|X_n|>x) = 0$, and was trying to work around it. However, still can't figure out how to make the $A_n/n$ appear. For the second question, you were right I misinterpreted it and already figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overthinking the first one..

You said you already have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}P(|X_n|>x)=0$$

Since $1/2^n > 0$, this means there is some $x_n > 0$ such that $$P(|X_n| > x_n) \leq 1/2^n.$$

Now just set $A_n = x_n \cdot n$.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it was the easiest part of the proof.